# UNION ALL columns with similar names SQL Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union-all

I have a set of tables that all have the following structure:

`member_ID | Aug_Date | Aug_Score | Aug_Activities...`

Every month, new columns are added (the original columns remain, and new ones are added):

`member_ID | Aug_Date | Aug_Score | Aug_Activities | Sep_Date | Sep_Score | Sep_Activities`

and so on for every month that follows...

I have 6 tables of this structure that I want to UNION ALL to become a table whose schema is this :

`member_ID| Test_Date | Test_Score | Test_Activities`

where every month's values gets appended to the final three columns (So `Aug_Date` **AND** `Sep_Date` values would go into `Test_Date` in the final table).

In order to achieve this, I can simply change column names each month as new tables enter our database, but I'd like to have this happen automatically. I use Big Query to store my project, so this method appends a new query's results every month, but I'd like to create a dynamic query that is able to recognize all column names of a particular structure (like `YYY_Date`) and append them all under one column (like in the example above). I'd like to create a query that will override the previous table with values from all available months. Is this possible?

Comment: You should improve the design of your database. Adding a new column every month is a bad idea. You should add rows not columns.

Comment: You should have 1 column that says MONTHBEGINDT and then with each month just populate another block of rows with that date. You can always pivot the data to look like how you want it, at any time, and you can even save a view that does this for you. However the table itself you should not be adding columns like this. This is not some minor opinionated response, we're trying to save you from yourself, trust us.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have no control over how the CSV is constructed which is why I am looking for this dynamic response. This is how the system that I am working with generates results over time. I'm basically developing a query to pull ANY date column under a column like the MONTHBEGINDT you're suggesting. Working through some possibilities now!

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to create a dynamic query that is able to recognize all column names of a particular structure (like YYY_Date) and append them all under one column (like in the example above).

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS 
  SELECT '1' member_ID, 'Aug 26, 2022' Aug_Date, 90 Aug_Score, 'mid-term' Aug_Activities,
                        'Sep 25, 2022' Sep_Date, 80 Sep_Score, 'fin-term' Sep_Activities
   UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' member_ID, 'Aug 26, 2022' Aug_Date, 70 Aug_Score, 'mid-term' Aug_Activities,
                        'Sep 25, 2022' Sep_Date, 60 Sep_Score, 'fin-term' Sep_Activities
;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(test, ' UNION ALL') FROM (
    SELECT FORMAT("""
             SELECT member_ID, %s_Date Test_Date, %s_Score Test_Score, %s_Activities Test_Activities
               FROM sample_table
           """, mon, mon, mon) AS test
      FROM (SELECT * FROM sample_table LIMIT 1) t,
    UNNEST (REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'(\w{3})_Date')) mon
  )
);
```

[image]

And,

> I'd like to create a query that will override the previous table with values from all available months.

You can add **CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `your-dataset.your_table` AS** in front of dynamic sql like below.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `your-dataset.your_table` AS ' || STRING_AGG(test, ' UNION ALL') FROM (
   ...
```